# Print the powerset

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, backtracking

Why is the below code for printing the powerset of a set of integers, giving wrong answer? Actually, it is only printing empty set. What mistake am I making?

```
vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>>subset;
        vector<int>v;
        dfs(subset,0,nums,v);
        return subset;
    }
    void dfs(vector<vector<int>> subset, int index, vector<int>&nums, vector<int>&v){
        subset.push_back(v);
        for(int i=index;i<nums.size();i++)
        {
            v.push_back(nums[i]);
            dfs(subset,i+1,nums,v);
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please incldue a [mcve], desired and actual output in the question

Comment: Are you aware that you pass `subset` by value to `dfs()`? So, if you leave `dfs()` you will lose whatever you pushed back to it. To me, it looks like it should be `void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &subset, ...` instead. Otherwise, `return subset;` (in `subsets()`) will obviously return an empty vector of vectors always.

Comment: You're altering a local copy of your subset in dfs. If you expect the dfs function to alter its argument, you should accept a reference and not a value.

Comment: also you first push `v` to `subset` and then you push more stuff to `v`. But after `subset.push_back(v);` you then have the orginal vector `v` and a copy of it inside `subset`. Modifying `v` will not affect the copy in the vector. This might be desired, but at least it looks fishy

Comment: `subsets` prints only empty `subset` because `dfs` function had never changed it

Comment: Yeah, in summary, C++ is not Java/C#, Java/C# is not C++. Get a book (that's an actual advise).

Comment: there is more than one mistake in the code. For a complete answer, please post a complete example. The code you posted does not print anything, so we cannot know for sure what makes your real code print an empty set. We see some mistakes, but depending on the code you did not post, the actual problem could be elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing subset by value to dfs function. Try pass it by reference or by address. Otherwise your subset will not be changed.

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> & subset, ...)
```